# sql server 2005 service will not start once remote connections is turned on

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have been looking for a solutions for this problem for days now. I have a new server running server 2003 and sql server 2005. When I turn on allow remote connections using tcp or any other options and restart the sql service, the service will not start. If I turn off allow remote connections I can then start the sql service with no problems. Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to a conflict between the two SQL servers configurations of between the SQL 2005 and another program. Look at the NT event log for more details on the failure, but I'll wager a beer that the TCP port the remote connection is trying to listen on is already taken by SQL 2003 or somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this site can provide some insight.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/vbgeneral/thread/f084daa5-bee1-4200-9820-56e8faa94788

Answer (score 0):

thank you, it makes a lot of sense. I had orginally installed sql 2008. The software provider informed me that I had to have sql 2005 instead. So I uninstalled 2008 and loaded sql 2005. I will check the server for that folder and remove it and see what happens. Really appreciate it, will let you know what happens.
Mike